# Writing a filename with "/ " - Sign in Python without opening a new directory

Tags: python, plot, path, plotly

I'm currently working on a bulk export of generated images. And several hundred files cannot be written because their name "/" is present.

i.e., Filename: `foo_ ba1 / ba2.html`

This leads Python to think to go to a new directory. But I want the image as .html with a name containing "/". And not a new PATH.

For writing the files, I currently use Plotly. express with a formatted string, which includes a varible (here ba), which sometimes (several 100) contains "/"

i.e.

`fig.writ_html(f"my_path/image{foo}_{ba}.html")`

I've tryed to write everything in a string, I've used differend quote signes " ' `´.
And I don't know how to search further for the issue, I'm missing words :/

Thank you for your support.

Comment: `/` is never valid in a file name, not in *nix based, nor in Windows based OS's. So the answer is you cannot. You should rewrite your code to not use `/` in the filenames.

Comment: I was hoping for a workarround, i.e. defining the name of the file a to string and ignore the /.

Comment: You could replace the `/` characters with something else using the `.replace()` function.

Comment: Jub, this is how I did it for now... 
But thanks a lot for your answers :)